# Stretch images to the edge of browser and automatically resize with browser's size

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

I'm new to HTML and CSS and I've searched for similar questions but couldn't find the one that matched my situation. I'm making my portfolio page and would like to display the thumbnails/images like this website does: http://knockinc.com/work/

There's no gap between images and they are stretched to the edge of the browser. The images also resize proportionally with the browser's size.

Here's an example of where I am so far: https://codepen.io/jennycysun/pen/BwrWzb?editors=1100 
I'd like to have 3 images max in a row.
(I'm only allowed to post CSS code here, so for both HTML and CSS code, please visit the codepen link above.)

```
body{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.puppies ul{
list-style-type:none;
padding: 0;
margin-top: 50px;
}

.puppies li{
display: inline-block;
postition: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: -2px;
margin-top: -4px; 
}

img{
max-width: 100%;
}
```

I couldn't figure out how to make images reach the edge of browser and  automatically resize. Please advise me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```css
body {margin: 0}

.puppies {
  column-count: 3; /* three images in a row */
  column-gap: 0; /* adjust if you want gaps between images */
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid-column;
}

.puppies > img {
  display: block; /* removes bottom margin/whitespace */
  width: 100%; /* responsiveness */
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .puppies {column-count: 2} /* two images in a row */
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .puppies {column-count: 1} /* one image in a row */
}
```

```html
<div class="puppies">
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/b9lb-T9FrAg/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://cdn.thinglink.me/api/image/703615529729916929/1240/10/scaletowidth" alt="">
  <img src="https://cdn.akc.org/Marketplace/Breeds/Siberian_Husky_SERP.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="http://i.huffpost.com/gen/2709324/images/o-BULLDOG-PUPPY-facebook.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="http://tailandfur.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/40-Amazing-Poodle-Dog-Puppy-Pictures-2.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

I recommend you to always use images with the same width and height but that's up to you, not mandatory. You can adjust media queries screen width's to your needs but the ones I used are pretty common nowadays. If you need any additional help, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use specific width and height in image and add percentage in css code like below

**CSS**

```
.puppies li{
  display: inline-block;
  postition: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: -2px;
  margin-top: -4px; 
width:20%/*Just add this line*/
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class=puppies>
<ul>
  <li><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/b9lb-T9FrAg/maxresdefault.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="https://cdn.thinglink.me/api/image/703615529729916929/1240/10/scaletowidth" ></li>
  <li><img src="https://cdn.akc.org/Marketplace/Breeds/Siberian_Husky_SERP.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="http://i.huffpost.com/gen/2709324/images/o-BULLDOG-PUPPY-facebook.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="http://tailandfur.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/40-Amazing-Poodle-Dog-Puppy-Pictures-2.jpg"></li>
```

**EDIT**
Try this css code

```
.puppies li{
  display: inline-block;
  postition: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: -2px;
  margin-top: -4px; 
  width:33.33%;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! But since the original images' width and height are different, how do I make them the same height if I don't specify that in html? And how do I have only 3 images max in a row instead of having all 5 images in a row?  Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer! It still doesn't look like what I'm looking for as I wanted to make the images responsive. Sorry I should've phrased my question in a better way earlier. But I really appreciate your time! I definitely learned something else from your answer.